# If $X$ is a metric space with infinitely many connected components, is $X$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am having trouble with the following question. Can anyone help?

- Suppose $(X ,d)$ is a  metric space which has infinitely many distinct connected components. Then is $X$ compact?

Can anyone help me with a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is no link in general between the number of connected components and compacity. A compact space can have either infinitely many connected components (eg. Cantor set) or finitely many (eg. $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \cup ... \cup [2n,2n+1]$); a non compact space can have either infinitely many connected components (see Zev Chonoles' answer) or finitely many (eg. $\mathbb{R}^n$).

However, if your space $X$ is supposed to be locally connected, then the connected components of $X$  are open; therefore, if $X$ is compact, it has finitely many such components.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What are the connected components of a metric space with the discrete metric? When is a metric space with the discrete metric compact?

Comment: How does this help answer the question?

Comment: @Chris: An infinite set with the discrete metric has infinitely many connected components and is not compact.

Comment: Can you please tell me , can we find infinte many connected components of a compact , Hausdorff topological space .

Answer (score 1):

To pile on Zev's answer, discrete metric spaces are locally compact, but you can find a non-locally compact and totally disconnected space: $\Bbb Q$.