# Class $C^1$ function on a compact set

Tags: calculus

The problem is:

Let **g** be of class $C^1$ on $\Delta$⊂$ℝ^n$ and K be a compact subset of Δ. Show that there is a number C such that |**g**(**s**)-**g**(**t**)|≤C|**s**-**t**| for every **s**,**t**∈K.

---

I have proved that it is true when K is convex, but I do not know how to proceed.
Anyone could help me to solve this question?

Thanks

Comment: is $\Delta$ open? or how are $C^1$ functions on $\Delta$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $\Delta$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $g$ is $C^1$ then it is locally lipschitz (to prove this fact you can use the strategy you have used in the case $K$ convex, that is the intermediate value theorem I think).

Now locally lipschitz functions on compact sets are globally lipschitz, and this can be proved by covering argument ( See [if locally Lipschitz implies Lipschitz on compacts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154721/if-locally-lipschitz-implies-lipschitz-on-compacts) )