# If a product of a Lipschitz function and another bounded function is Lipschitz, is the other function Lipschitz?

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, almost-everywhere

Let $x=[0,1]^n,\;p: [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]^n$. Define $V(x) = p(x).x$, i.e. the inner product of $p(x)$ and $x$. We are given $V(.)$ is convex. Can we say $p(x)$ is Lipschitz?

My approach: $V(.)$ is convex, therefore locally Lipschitz. [We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154721/in-mathbbrn-locally-lipschitz-on-compact-set-implies-lipschitz), locally Lipschitz on a compact set implies Lipschitz. Therefore $V(.)$ is Lipschitz. My question is, does this imply $p(x)$ is Lipschitz or at least almost everywhere differentiable?

I tried to do the following but could  not proceed further:

$\lim\limits_{u \rightarrow u_0} |V(u_0) - V(u)| = \lim\limits_{u \rightarrow u_0} |p(u_0).(u - u_0) + u.(p(u) - p(u_0))| = \lim\limits_{u \rightarrow u_0} |u.(p(u) - p(u_0))|$

Answer (score 0):

When $n=1$ and $p(x)=\sqrt x$ is is clear that $p$ is not Lipschitz but $xp(x)$ is convex and Lipschitz (it has a bounded derivative).

Comment: As I said in the question, almost everywhere differentiability is fine too. $\sqrt x$ is almost everywhere differentiable in $[0,1]$ or $\mathbb{R_{+}}$. 
Is there a counterexample where the function in question is not almost everywhere differentiable? That would be great. Thank you in advance.